# Android "Roboto Light" pixelation

Tags: android, fonts, typography

I'm including the Roboto family of fonts in my application, and create the fonts in code like so:

```
Typeface robotoLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
```

I have noticed that certain smaller sizes  (even the suggested sizes from the [Android Developer Typography page](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html)) appear distorted or pixelated. Here is a screenshot of a few `TextView`s in the app:

[image: roboto_pixelated]

"Upcoming Dates" uses a larger size and looks fine. The other ones are sized at 14sp and look awful. The problem is not with margin or padding in the `TextView`s -- I've tried altering both.  Does anyone know what causes this problem, and how to fix it?

Comment: This question is amazing!!! +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following on each of your TextViews with the custom typeface:

```
int flags = textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG
            | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG;
textView.setPaintFlags(flags);
```